# Подскажите, как обновить MSBuild для VS2019

Tags: visual-studio, msbuild

Я получил ошибку

```
Invalid static method invocation syntax:
"[MSBuild]::AreFeaturesEnabled('16.8')".
Не найден метод "[MSBuild]::AreFeaturesEnabled".
Static method invocation should be of the form:
$([FullTypeName]::Method()), e.g. $([System.IO.Path]::Combine(`a`, `b`)).
Check that all parameters are defined, are of the correct type,
and are specified in the right order.

C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Enterprise\MSBuild\Current\Bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets
```

нашёл в сети, что проблема решается

```
https://github.com/dotnet/msbuild/issues/6329
```

если обновить Microsoft.Build `from 16.5.0 to 16.9.0`

Подскажите, как узнать, какая у меня версия MSBuild и как её обновить ?